# How can I restrict a pod to contact other pods directly but allowing access via service

Tags: kubernetes

1. Let's say,I have 3 nginx pods listening over port 80.
2. Let's say, I have once service `nginx-svc` of type `ClusterIP`, listening over port `8080` and forwarding requests to above nginx pods over port `80`.
3. Let's say, I have another pod `busybox`.

How can I configure the `network-policy` to allow `busybox`
pod to access `nginx` pods only via service `nginx-svc` but not directly?

Comment: you can't. and you should not need to do that.

Comment: As specified in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), network policy only operates at pod level: "A network policy is a specification of how groups of pods are allowed to communicate with each other and other network endpoints.", so I guess the answer is you can't.

That is quite a weird requirement, any particular reason you want to do that?

Comment: Agreed. No practical use-case.
Just thought that since pods access can be restricted and pods can interact via services and with `network-policy` it's as easy as using selectors to control the access, so assumed there might be a way to restrict via services also, but not mentioned in the documentation. Thank you for double confirming.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve it the way yo presented it but you can [restrict access to the pod for specific service and labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/#limit-access-to-the-nginx-service) using `NetworkPolicy`.

For example, if you have deployment with labels `app: nginx` (you can create it using `kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`) and you expose it, by using `kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80` you can create following NetworkPolicy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels: #mutable fields
          access: "true"
```

It will restrict access to pods with only labels `app=nginx` and `access="true"`.

After this network policy is applied, you can create busybox pod with labels `access="true"` it will be able to communicate with those pods.